# Do people pay over asking price and get a refund from the seller?

Tags: real-estate

I found a nice property for 60k. I asked my lender if there was a minimum loan amount and he said No. I made an offer on the property for 55k and it was accepted. Now that same lender says he thinks the minimum is 60k. Can I pay asking price and get a refund check from the seller? I'm in the US.

Comment: Find a different lender?

Comment: Hope your offer has a mortgage contingency if this is a difficult loan to get in practice

Answer (score 2):

Doing what your asking seems to be evading the rules governing your mortgage. You are essentially getting a 'cash back' mortgage, meaning you will owe 60k, own a 55k house, and have 5k in cash sitting at home. Maybe the bank is okay with this, but I would assume that before they sign off on the mortgage they will want to see a house worth 60k, not a house worth 55k.

Consult your lender about what to do in this scenario, and as suggested, consult other lenders as well. Definitely don't try to misconstrue the true purchase price of the home to your bank.

Comment: If the bank allowed that, i'd just turn immediately around and pay the $5k back to them to reduce the principal to 55k.  They might not like that.

Comment: @Harper Agreed - I think that highlights very clearly why at least this bank in particular wouldn't be okay with this [because they have the 60k limit, so doing this would leave the bank with only a 55k mortgage owned].

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen a buyer offering more in an effort to get cash back, however, I have seen a seller build extra into an asking price then give cash back as an allowance for improvements. An example would be if I'm selling my home and it has old carpet I could sell the house and build an allowance of say $1500 into the selling price then give them that amount back at closing.

Comment: Would the bank like that though? Because to me it seems that the bank is lending money on the assumption that the house is worth the full purchase price. Don't want to misconstrue how much is actually being paid for the house vs improvements...

Comment: In this case there is nothing being hidden from the bank. It would be in the contact that the home is seeking for X amount where some portion is being returned to the buyer as an allowance for improvement Y. The loan amount the bank will approve is based in large part on the appraised value of the property. If I am pre-approved for 200k and the house I want appraises for 100k the bank will not give me 200k for the home for improvements. If it appraises for 190k and the seller asks 190k with a 5k allowance for a new furnace for example, the bank would approve. The seller gets 18m80

Comment: @Grade 'Eh' Bacon Sorry, app didn't let me finish my edit to fix my button mashing and finish my comment. In the case of the 190k example the bank would approve, the seller would get 190k with 5k being given to the buyer for the furnace. The key is that the whole transaction is transparent, there is nothing hidden from the lender and everything falls within the bounds of the appraised value of the home.

Comment: Right, I absolutely agree with you - I only wanted to point it out for the case of the OP, who seems to be in a similar-ish situation and has not clearly said they are being upfront with the bank about it.

Comment: @Grade 'Eh' Bacon  I'm not sure this would apply as well to the OP'S question as it would when buying a home. I suppose if you were getting the additional funds to make some sort of improvement to the property such as a road or sewage line or something then it might apply the same. Without better understanding the OP's situation it is pretty much speculation on our part to answer.